# What am I supposed to prove here actually?

Tags: calculus, continuity

I got problems understanding the task:

> Prove that there are at least two different $x \in  (0, 2)$ such that $x^3-x-\sqrt{x} +\frac{1}{2}= 0$.

The given hint is to use the *intermediate value theorem*.

What confuses me is that there is no $f(x) =\dots$; instead of it, there is a zero.
If there was no zero, I would start by $f(0) = \dots$ and $f(2) = \dots$ then check which is greater / smaller and finish the proof, something like that yeah.

But what else shall I do now when there is a zero instead of $f(x)$?
Am I supposed to prove that the zero point of this is at $(0, 2)$?
Probably not because then I don't see why they give us the hint to use the *intermediate value theorem*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $f$ is $f(x)=x^3-x-\sqrt{x} +\frac{1}{2}$ and you easily find that $f(0)=1/2,\;$ $f(1)=-1/2,\;$ $f(2) = 13/2-\sqrt {2}>0$. Since $f$ is continuous,  the  intermediate value theorem shows that there are two $x$ values $x_1 \in (0,1)$ and $x_2 \in (1,2)$ with $f(x_i)=0$.

Comment: This is the proof really? I also didn't know we can put f(x) instead of zero, good to know :P

Comment: $f(1)$ has two different values?

Comment: I think he has a typo yes

Comment: @Byron Schmuland: corrected! Thank you.

Comment: @berndgr this sort of things is pretty standard in exercise about the IVT. You have something and you want to show it is zero at some point; so all you have to do is *define* $f$ as your something, and you get a function on which you can apply your theorem (if it's continuous, of course).

Comment: One more question, how do you know the function is continuous? I would say if we draw it, there won't be any definition gaps, so we can draw it without releasing the pen. Any more professional reasons you can tell me? Also there is no division here, so seems continuous. But I'm scared they ask "how do you assume it is continuous?".

Comment: @berndgr: Note that addition and subtraction of continuous functions is again a continuous function.

Comment: You know that the powers $x^n$ are continous, and $\sqrt{x}$ for $x\ge 0$. And the sum of continous functions is continous.

Comment: You are right, thank you very much :D
Good things to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You say that you do not know how to approach the following.

> Prove that there are at least two different $x \in  (0, 2)$ such that $x^3-x-\sqrt{x} +\frac{1}{2}= 0$.

You also say, if I understand you correctly, that you would feel less lost if the question was:

> Let $f(x)=x^3-x-\sqrt{x} +\frac{1}{2}$. Prove that there are at least two different $x \in  (0, 2)$ such that $f(x)=0$.

Now these two questions are exactly the same, the only difference is that in the second version the expression has been given the name $f$. Of course, you are allowed to name things in your proof.

So just start your prove with:

> Let $f(x)=x^3-x-\sqrt{x} +\frac{1}{2}$.

Not however, that since *you* are defining the function, you also should specify its domain.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that for $x \in [0,2]$:

$f(x)=x^3-x-\sqrt{x} +\frac{1}{2}$

$f(0)=\frac{1}{2}$

$f(1)=-\frac{1}{2}$

$f(2)>5$

The intermediate value theorem says that if $f$ is continuous in the domain and $c \in (f(a),f(b))$ then there exists a  $c_0 \in (a,b)$ or $c_0 \in (b,a)$ such that $f(c_0)=c$.

$0 \in (f(1),f(0))$ so there exists $f(c_0)=0$ where $c_0 \in (0,1)$...

Comment: It is better mention that you are considering $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ or at least  $f:[0,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ because otherwise you can't take $x=0$ and $x=2$.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll mention it.

Comment: The idea is right, but $f(2)\neq 5$...

Comment: Thanks @ArnaudD. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function 
$$
f(x)=x^3−x−\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{2}
$$
Note that $f(1/16)=769/4096>0$ , $f(1)=-1/2<0$ , $f(25/16)=6153/4096>0$. Hence by the intermediate value theorem there exist $x_1\in(1/16,1)$ and $x_2\in(1,25/16)$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$, as requared.

Comment: Why f(1/16)? You just choose some random value and put it into the function?

Comment: I wanted to choose a value inside the interval that i can compute without using a calculator. Actually, it more easy to use $f(0)$ and $ f(2)$ since our function is continues for $0\leq x$